# Duplicate file naming on save

Tags: java, model-view-controller, filestream

i am working on my word Processor and i have managed to get the save file to work. However i am encountering an annoying error where saving the file will cause the file name (which is typed in) to duplicate itself  for example, say you type in a file name "test" the file would save and it would appear as "testtest.txt". I also would highly appreciate a code review, if it can be offered.
I am also trying to adhere to the MVC (model view controller paradigm) and i am wondering if i am correctly doing it, can i abstract this further, anyways here is my code:
Model

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DataStuff {

    private File file;

    String text;
    String name;
    private File saveFile;
    int counter = 0;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4096);

    int count = 0;
    public void loadFile(File fileName){
        this.file = fileName;
        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            while ((counter = fis.read()) != -1) {

                System.out.print((char) counter);

                sb.append((char) counter);

            }

        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("file couldn't be opened, or was incorrect or you clicked cancel");
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public StringBuilder showText(){

        return sb;

    }
    public void saveFile(String name, String text) {
        this.name = name;

        try{                
                fout = new FileOutputStream(name);  
                fout.write(text.getBytes());
                System.out.println("file saving worked");           
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("File failed to save or something went horribly wrong");
        }       
    }   
}
```

this is the View.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class WordFrame extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JMenuBar menubar;
    private JMenu fileMenu, editMenu, viewMenu;
    JMenuItem saveMenuItem, openMenuItem, newMenuItem, exitMenuItem, FontMenuItem;
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(1000,900);
    private int width = 1280, height = 980;
    private JScrollPane scrollbar = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    private int textHeight = 12;
    private Font yeah = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, 2, textHeight);

    public WordFrame(){
        setUI();
        addMenuBar();   
        textArea.setFont(yeah);
    }

    public void setUI(){
        this.setTitle("Word Processor");
        this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Bridge.jpg")).getImage());
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setLocation(0,0);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(scrollbar);

    }

    public void addMenuBar(){
        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu(" File ");
        editMenu = new JMenu("Edit ");
        viewMenu = new JMenu("View ");

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.setMnemonic('f');

        openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");

        fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);

        saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);

        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

        FontMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Font");
        editMenu.add(FontMenuItem);
        menubar.add(fileMenu);
        menubar.add(editMenu);
        menubar.add(viewMenu);      

        this.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    }

    public void setFontSize(int i){
        this.textHeight = i;
    }
    public void addListener(ActionListener listener){
        openMenuItem.addActionListener(listener);
        exitMenuItem.addActionListener(listener);
        saveMenuItem.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}
```

and finally the controller

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;



public class ProcessEvents {

    private WordFrame frame = new WordFrame();
    private DataStuff data = new DataStuff();
    private DialogBoxes dialogs = new DialogBoxes();
    private boolean fileSaved;
    String fileName = "";
    int fontSize = 0;
    public ProcessEvents(WordFrame frame, DataStuff data){
        this.frame = frame;
        this.data = data;
        this.frame.addListener(new wordProcessListener());
    }
    class wordProcessListener implements ActionListener{

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource().equals(frame.openMenuItem)){
                frame.fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
                File f = frame.fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

                System.out.println("Command Executed: open");

                data.loadFile(f.getAbsoluteFile());

                if(data.showText() != null){                    
                    System.out.println(data.showText());                
                    frame.textArea.append(data.showText().toString());
                }
            }

            if(e.getSource().equals(frame.FontMenuItem)){
                System.out.println("font");
            }

            if(e.getSource().equals(frame.exitMenuItem)){
                dialogs.getConfirmDialog("exitWithoutSave");
            }

            if(e.getSource().equals(frame.saveMenuItem)){
                frame.fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
                File f = frame.fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                String text = frame.textArea.getText();
                data.saveFile(f.getAbsolutePath()+f.getName()+".txt", text);
                System.out.println(f.getName());
                fileSaved = true;

            }           
        }       
    }
}
```

I intend to implement features such as font selection etc. I would highly appreciate a critique on my code any weaknesses that i have failed to spot etc and as always i highly appreciate any feedback.

edit: also i would like to ask, another annoying aspect is if you decide to cancel on saving the file i get a stack trace saying file is null any solutions, because i tried to add an if block in the saveFile method in DataStuff and it didn't work so its happening in the controller.

Comment: Not wanting to be picky but the code you have labelled as the model appears to be the view.

Comment: JamesB yeah you're right mislabeled it. Going to change it now just in case someone gets confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicated name is because you are doing  `f.getAbsolutePath()+f.getName()+".txt"` - I think that `getAbsolutePath` already includes the file name.

For a code review there is a stack exchange site set up for just that, you will get a better response there.

Comment: yeah i will take it up there, but i wanted to know if i could hit two birds with one stone. I will check up with the response you have given

Comment: Yes this worked like a charm. problem fixed, thank you. Quickest fix ever, so fast in fact i still have to wait 7 minutes before i can click accept answer lol.